# nomencl package : sort by order of appearance

Tags: nomencl

In the `nomencl` package, how can I make the symbols print by order of appearance in the LaTeX code?

Comment: I'm not aware of an easy way to do this with `nomencl`. Are you committed to `nomencl` or would you consider changing packages? (It can easily be done with `glossaries` via the `sort=use` option but that package has a different interface, so it's not straight-forward to convert.)

Comment: @NicolaTalbot not really, but I have already a full document using `nomencl`, so switching to `glossaries` would be quite annoying.

Comment: @unknownSoldier Okay. Just thought I'd mention it on the off-chance. Maybe someone more familiar with `nomencl` can suggest something.

Answer (score 9):

As far as I know, `nomencl` does not support this out of the bag. Here's a hacky way to do it instead.

Basically it is a redefinition of the `\nomenclature[]{}{}` command, to **ignore the sorting argument** (i.e. the optional argument in `\nomenclature`) and to use a counter-based sorting method instead.
Whenever `\nomenclature` is called, the counter `@nomcount` raises by one. We then take advantage of `makeindex`'s sorting algorithm which treats numbers as per normal (`8`<`34`<`111`), and so the entries will be printed in order of use.

I have included a toggle for you to switch this sorting behaviour 'on' and 'off'. With

```
\settoggle{nomsort}{<bool>}
```

If `<bool>` is set to `true`, then we activate `sort by use` (which is your desired effect). If `<bool>` is set to `false` then we return to normal usage of `nomencl` (using the optional argument of `\nomenclature` and what not).

[image: nomensrt]

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[]{nomencl}   
    \makenomenclature

\providetoggle{nomsort}
\settoggle{nomsort}{true} % true = sort by use, false = sort as usual

\makeatletter
\iftoggle{nomsort}{%
    \let\old@@@nomenclature=\@@@nomenclature        
        \newcounter{@nomcount} \setcounter{@nomcount}{0}%
        \renewcommand\the@nomcount{\two@digits{\value{@nomcount}}}% Ensure 10>01
        \def\@@@nomenclature[#1]#2#3{% Taken from package documentation
          \addtocounter{@nomcount}{1}%
        \def\@tempa{#2}\def\@tempb{#3}%
          \protected@write\@nomenclaturefile{}%
          {\string\nomenclatureentry{\the@nomcount\nom@verb\@tempa @[{\nom@verb\@tempa}]%
          \begingroup\nom@verb\@tempb\protect\nomeqref{\theequation}%
          |nompageref}{\thepage}}%
          \endgroup
          \@esphack}%
      }{}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
    \nomenclature{$j$}{Appears first} 
    \nomenclature{$i$}{Appears second}
    \nomenclature{$h$}{Appears third}
    \nomenclature{$g$}{Appears fourth}
    \nomenclature{$f$}{Appears fifth}
    \nomenclature{$e$}{Appears sixth}
    \nomenclature{$d$}{Appears seventh}
    \nomenclature{$c$}{Appears eighth}
    \nomenclature{$b$}{Appears ninth}
    \nomenclature{$a$}{Appears tenth~(last)}
    \printnomenclature

    Note that $d$ appears first because it is declared first.

    Note also the 10th entry is sorted after the 9th.
\end{document}
```

To be honest, though, it's probably easier and more consistent to do it with the `glossaries` package, as @NicolaTalbot mentioned in the comments.

Comment: thanks! But this solution does not interact well with the `subfiles` package, which I am using...

Comment: @unknownSoldier Please provide a minimal working example (complete with documentclass and the included packages) that we can compile and that demonstrates the problem you are facing, i.e. what does "does not interact well" mean?

Comment: I don't know the reason, but this hacky gets messy when the list have more than ten items...

Comment: It works fine now :)

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba Thanks for letting me know. Cheers.

Comment: Me again: same problem, but now for more than one hundred items - I know, it looks like I'm writing a big text.  I naively tried to replace \two@digits with \three@digits, but it didn't work.

Comment: @RenanManeliMezabarba Define your own `\three@digits`: `\def\three@digits#1{\ifnum#1<100 0\ifnum#1<10 0\fi\fi\number#1}` in the preamble.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I'll come back here when I get to the "thousand" version of  the issue lol

Comment: I don't see the advantage of `\string\nomenclatureentry{\the@nomcount\nom@verb\@tempa` over `\string\nomenclatureentry{#1\the@nomcount\nom@verb\@tempa`, the former [breaks nomencl's approach to grouping to create multiple lists](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/682338/106162) without obvious benefit.

Answer (score 2):

Let us say that you want to print variables z,y and x using nomencl with

```
z coming first followed by y and x. You key in the code as below: 

\nomenclature{$z$}{This is the first variable}

\nomenclature{$y$}{This is the second variable}

\nomenclature{$x$}{This is the third variable}

\printnomenclature
```

The nomenclature package sorts the variables in alphabetical order. The default output for an input code given above will be:

[image: Undesired Output]

which may not be the desired one. To generate the nomenclature list in the input order (in the order as they appear) can be accomplished by the including the order number within the optional square brackets. The modified code with a longer list of variables is illustrated below:

```
\nomenclature[[1]]{$z$}{This is the first variable}

\nomenclature[[2]]{$y$}{This is the second variable}

\nomenclature[3]{$x$}{This is the third variable}

\nomenclature[4]{$w$}{This is the fourth variable}

\nomenclature[5]{$v$}{This is the fifth variable}

\nomenclature[6]{$u$}{This is the sixth variable}

\nomenclature[7]{$t$}{This is the seventh variable}

\nomenclature[8]{$s$}{This is the eighth variable}

\nomenclature[9]{$r$}{This is the ninth variable}

\nomenclature[a1]{$q$}{This is the tenth variable}

\nomenclature[a2]{$p$}{This is the eleventh variable}

\printnomenclature
```

The desired output appears below:

[image: Desired Output]

Note the numbering scheme used within the square brackets to extend beyond 10 variables. Hope this helps. Thank you.